# Selecting a GWT ComboBox item displays the value and not the text

Tags: java, gwt, combobox, editor, gxt

Using Java and GWT, I have a contentGrid with a custom column definition and a content Store.

One of the columns of the grid needs to show a combo box with several options.  The combo box and its contents are defined as such:

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
SimpleStore comboBoxStore = new SimpleStore( new String[]{"text","id"}, new String[][] { new String[] {"John", "Mike"} , new String[] {"1","2"} } );
comboBoxStore.load();
comboBox.setDisplayField( "text" );
comboBox.setValueField("id" );
comboBox.setStore( comboBoxStore );
comboBox.setForceSelection( true );
comboBox.setEditable( false );

nameColumnConfig.setEditor(new GridEditor( comboBox ));
```

The grid then displays correctly, double-clicking the nameColumnConfig displays the combo box with the correct elements "John" and "Mike".

But when I click on one of those options and click away for the grid so it "updates" itself, the combobox displays the id of the selected option and not it's displayField.

I've been looking for a solution for some time, and I haven't found anything that could remotely let me know how to solve it or what's the cause.

I would greatly appreciate any help or insight in this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I feared this question might have been way too specific.  I've searched and some people have had similar problems but using gtw-ext in javascript.  Their solutions don't seem to apply to a java-based project.  I'm still stuck with this problem...

Comment: I found a thread on an extjs forum http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?39546-FIXED-2.1-Bug-when-a-ComboBox-is-used-as-an-EditorGridPanel-editor.  A bug is reported about the store filter not being cleared.  Not sure if this is the problem on the gwt framework, but I'll dig into it meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting like this---

```
comboBox.setDisplayField( "text" ); 
comboBox.setValueField("id" );
```

You have to do like

```
comboBox.setDisplayField( "text" ); 
comboBox.setValueField("text" );
```

sure , you will get an answer.